# I want to iterate over a loop and calculate total time till the condition lasts else total time till the condition doesn't last in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, data-analysis

```
 I have this kind of data:(given below):

[![This is my sample data][1]][1]

  
    RegistrationNo  EventType   StartDateTime        EndDateTime            Duration(inMins)
0   MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-13 16:46:00  2020-07-14 04:53:00    727.0
1   MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 04:53:00  2020-07-14 06:28:00    95.0
2   MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 06:28:00  2020-07-14 06:52:00    24.0
3   MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 06:52:00  2020-07-14 07:03:00    11.0
4   MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 07:03:00  2020-07-14 07:58:00    55.0
5   MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 07:58:00  2020-07-14 10:26:00    148.0
6   MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 10:26:00  2020-07-14 10:55:00    29.0
7   MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 10:55:00  2020-07-14 11:15:00    20.0
8   MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 11:15:00  2020-07-14 11:59:00    44.0
9   MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 11:59:00  2020-07-14 12:03:00    4.0
10  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 12:03:00  2020-07-14 16:18:00    255.0  
11  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 16:18:00  2020-07-14 16:19:00    1.0
12  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 16:19:00  2020-07-14 16:39:00    20.0
13  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 16:39:00  2020-07-14 18:20:00    101.0 
14  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 18:20:00  2020-07-14 20:22:00    122.0 
15  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-14 20:22:00  2020-07-14 21:41:00    79.0
16  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-14 21:41:00  2020-07-15 05:52:00    491.0
17  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-15 05:52:00  2020-07-15 07:37:00    105.0
18  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-15 07:37:00  2020-07-16 05:17:00    1300.0
19  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-16 05:17:00  2020-07-16 06:23:00    66.0
20  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-16 06:23:00  2020-07-16 08:11:00    108.0
21  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-16 08:11:00  2020-07-16 08:13:00    2.0
22  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-16 08:14:00  2020-07-16 09:22:00    68.0
23  MH-04-**-****   Transit     2020-07-16 09:22:00  2020-07-16 09:28:00    6.0
24  MH-04-**-****   Stop        2020-07-16 09:28:00  2020-07-16 09:45:00    17.0
```

I want to make one program where I want to check in every 4 hours of driving how much time it is taking break and if it's not taking total break of more than 1 hour then for how much time it has driven continuously ignoring total break less than 60mins/ 1 hour break in 1st 4 hour interval.

Some points for details:

Driving more than 4 hours without a break of at least 1 hour in total. The break of 1 hour can be divided into breaks of 15 minutes each.

Each hour of continuous driving beyond 4 hours will be counted as 1 instance. E.g. if the vehicle drives for 5 hours and 2 minutes at a stretch then the count will be 2 (5th hour and the 2 minutes of 6th hour)

I have tried many things but not able to cover this all conditions.

Please help, now you guys are only hope! thanks in advance!

Comment: Just one remark and some questions. 1/ You should first try to solve it yourself and show a *honest* attempt. 2/ do you want to considere overlapping periods of 4 hours or only consecutive periods? 3/ in the example each row has a start time equals to the end time of the previous row. Is is consistent or could there be *holes* or overlaps in the dataframe?

Comment: 1. I am trying it since yesterday, even I ask friend but didn't work out..even I find loops confusing, plus there are so many conditions. :( .. and data is consistent, you can see as events are changing, once the one even changes second starts.

Comment: You still have not answered whether overlapping 4 hours periods should be considered (say 6:00 -> 10:00 then 6:05 ->10:05, etc.) or only consecutive ones (6:00 ->10:00 then 10:00 ->14:00). And even if your code *does not work*, it could help to show it (along with the current and expected behaviour) because others could explain you why it does not work ;-)

Comment: You can see the time period is consecutive already..and yeah you're making sense..:) let me add some then!

Comment: @SergeBallesta   if you're saying from (2nd row value)04:53:00 to 08:53:00 and then (next value)06:52:00 to 10:52:00 in then yes..yeah we need consider each and every transit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to know is whether there was more than 4 driving hours in any 5 hours period. Because it will caracterize any 4 driving hours with less than 1 break hour.

That can be obtained by first resampling the original data at a 1 minute frequency, and then use a rolling sum on a 5 hours period of transit minutes.

In Pandas it could give:

```
tmp = df.assign(Transit=(df['EventType'] == 'Transit')
                ).set_index('StartDateTime')['Transit'].append(
    pd.Series([df.iloc[-1]['EventType'] == 'Transit'],
              index=[df.iloc[-1]['EndDateTime']])
    ).resample('1T').ffill().iloc[:-1].rolling('5H').sum().astype('int32')
```

Details on the formula:

- `assign(Transit=(df['EventType'] == 'Transit')` identify transit times in a summable way
- `set_index('StartDateTime')['Transit']` use a datetime index to ease resampling and only considere the new `Transit` column (True == transit time)
- `append(pd.Series([df.iloc[-1]['Transit']], index=[df.iloc[-1]['EndDateTime']])` extends the series up to the end of the last period
- `resample('1T').ffill().iloc[:-1]` resample at a 1 minute interval and drop the last minute (else last period would be 1 minute too long)
- `rolling('5H').sum()` sum the total driving time on each 5 hours period
- `astype('int32')` `sum()` gives a float64 when an int32 is enough

You can now test for infractions as simply as `tmp[tmp > 240]`. With your sample it gives an empty Series.

To identify the different infractions, I cannot imagine a vectorized way, so I would fallback to a good old Python loop over the times where `tmp > 240`:

```
infrac = []
last = None
for i in tmp[tmp > 240].index:
    if (last is None) or (i >= last + pd.Timedelta('1H')): # one hour delay
        infrac.append(i)
        last = i
```

But I could not test much because the sample does not contain any infration...

---

Original answer that missed the point:

I could manage to compute the total break time for every sequence of 4 hours containing at least some transit. I assume that the dataframe contains no sequence of 4 hours or more of transit. That means that before using the following code, long driving sequences should be identified with:

```
df[(df['EventType'] == 'Transit')&(df['Duration(inMins)'] >= 240.)]
```

With the show data sample, the above query returns an empty dataframe.

I use `rolling` to identify sequences of 4 hours. As it uses the right end, I applied it on `EndDateTime`. And as only break time in the period of 4 hours has to be counted, I used a custom computational function.

Code is:

```
def sum_stop(x):
    x = df.loc[x.index]
    start = x.iloc[-1]['EndDateTime']-pd.Timedelta('4H')
    x = x[x['EventType'] == 'Stop']
    stop = np.where(x['StartDateTime']>=start, x['Duration(inMins)'],
                    (x['EndDateTime']-start).dt.total_seconds()/60.)
    return np.sum(stop)

df['BreakInPrevious4H'] = df.rolling('4H', on='EndDateTime')['Duration(inMins)'].apply(sum_stop)
```

It gives:

```
   RegistrationNo EventType       StartDateTime         EndDateTime  Duration(inMins)  BreakPrevious4H
0   MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-13 16:46:00 2020-07-14 04:53:00             727.0            240.0
1   MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 04:53:00 2020-07-14 06:28:00              95.0            145.0
2   MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 06:28:00 2020-07-14 06:52:00              24.0            145.0
3   MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 06:52:00 2020-07-14 07:03:00              11.0            134.0
4   MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 07:03:00 2020-07-14 07:58:00              55.0            134.0
5   MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 07:58:00 2020-07-14 10:26:00             148.0             79.0
6   MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 10:26:00 2020-07-14 10:55:00              29.0             84.0
7   MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 10:55:00 2020-07-14 11:15:00              20.0             72.0
8   MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 11:15:00 2020-07-14 11:59:00              44.0             73.0
9   MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 11:59:00 2020-07-14 12:03:00               4.0             73.0
10  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 12:03:00 2020-07-14 16:18:00             255.0            240.0
11  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 16:18:00 2020-07-14 16:19:00               1.0            239.0
12  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 16:19:00 2020-07-14 16:39:00              20.0            239.0
13  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 16:39:00 2020-07-14 18:20:00             101.0            138.0
14  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 18:20:00 2020-07-14 20:22:00             122.0            139.0
15  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-14 20:22:00 2020-07-14 21:41:00              79.0            122.0
16  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-14 21:41:00 2020-07-15 05:52:00             491.0            240.0
17  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-15 05:52:00 2020-07-15 07:37:00             105.0            135.0
18  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-15 07:37:00 2020-07-16 05:17:00            1300.0            240.0
19  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-16 05:17:00 2020-07-16 06:23:00              66.0            174.0
20  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-16 06:23:00 2020-07-16 08:11:00             108.0            174.0
21  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-16 08:11:00 2020-07-16 08:13:00               2.0            172.0
22  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-16 08:14:00 2020-07-16 09:22:00              68.0            176.0
23  MH-04-**-****   Transit 2020-07-16 09:22:00 2020-07-16 09:28:00               6.0            176.0
24  MH-04-**-****      Stop 2020-07-16 09:28:00 2020-07-16 09:45:00              17.0            193.0
```

Additional remarks: stops longer that 4 hours are not specially identified in the `BreakPrevious4H` column, but the actual duration is in `Duration(inMins)` (rows 0, 10, 16 and 18).

Comment: 1. This is a not a desired solution which I require..I think you didn't understand properly.Then let me explain you this. @SergeBallesta

Comment: I need to check in every 4 hours of transit( that means the vehicle is running) whether vehicle is taking at least 1 hour i.e. 60 mins break

Comment: and if not i.e if the vehicle is driving for 4 hours or more and the total break(that means stop event) is less than 60mins then each hour(5th hour) after those 4 hours of running will be considered as 1 instance(1 violation) and again if it runs for say 1 min to 60 min more then again it will be counted as 1 more instance and +1 will get added to that previous instance means till now the no. of instances is 2 ... and this way the process will continue. This way I just need that total no. of instance it has done and what date and time it was when it has done that? That's it! @SergeBallesta

Comment: Where? I cannot see?

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai: I put the new answer first, followed with original one...

Comment: There's an error in this line, could you just check!!      .append(pd.Series([df.iloc[-1]['Transit']], index=[df.iloc[-1]['EndDateTime']] ))   @SergeBallesta

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai: My bad. Was a previous version where I added the Transit column to the original dataframe. Fixed now.

Comment: See still I am getting the same error. You can check I have posted the error which I have got @SergeBallesta

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai: In my tests it works **with the sample data** where first 2 columns have object dtypes and contain strings, date columns have datetime64[ns] dtype and last is float64. I can only test with what you provide. BTW, I have read your edit and suspect the type of `EventType` to be a problem, but I rejected the edit because it has not to be part of the answer.

Comment: See the datatypes :  df.dtypes               RegistrationNo            object,
            EventType                 object,
          StartDateTime     datetime64[ns],
         EndDateTime       datetime64[ns],
Duration                 float64,
dtype: object @SergeBallesta

Comment: I think here in df.iloc[-1]['Transit'], Transit is not column and you are accessing it as column @SergeBallesta

Comment: @PriyankaS.Desai: Time for me to have a break... For a reason I cannot guess, I lost my edit :-( Should be better now...

Comment: You should take a break..you have been a sweetheart and helped me alot :) @SergeBallesta